# Joining URL throwing exception

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib

I have two variables, one containing the absolute URL, and another with the relative path to another section. First I tried just a simple concatenation.

```
absolute_url = www.example.com
relative_url = /downloads/images
url = absolute_url + relative_url
```

When I print the url variable, I have a well formed URL. But when I try to use requests or urllib2 to retrieve the data, about half the time it throws an exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Then I researched and thought that maybe I should use urllib.urlparse.urljoin() to do this, but I still get the error.

But what is intriguing to me is that sometimes it works and sometimes don't. Any ideas of what is going on here?

**EDIT**

Here is the actual code:

```
url = "http://www.hdwallpapers.in"
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)

categories = ("Nature", "Animals & Birds", "Beach", "Bikes", "Cars","Dreamy & Fantasy", "Others", "Travel & World")
random_category = random.randint(0, len(categories)) - 1
selected_category = categories[random_category]
selected_category_url = soup.find('a', text=selected_category)

category_page_url_join = urlparse.urljoin(url, selected_category_url['href'])
category_page_html = requests.get(category_page_url_join)
```

Comment: Show an actual example that goes wrong, including your use of requests/urllib2.

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of `categories`:

```
categories = ("Nature", "Animals & Birds", "Beach", "Bikes", "Cars","Dreamy & Fantasy", "Others", "Travel & World")
```

You're then picking one at random and searching for it:

```
random_category = random.randint(0, len(categories)) - 1
selected_category = categories[random_category]
selected_category_url = soup.find('a', text=selected_category)
```

This would be more easily written and just as readable as:

```
selected_category_url = soup.find('a', text=random.choice(categories))
```

Now your problem is no doubt coming from:

```
category_page_url_join = urlparse.urljoin(url, selected_category_url['href'])
```

This means that your `selected_category_url` ended up `None` because your `soup.find` didn't actually find anything. So in effect you're trying to run `None['href']` (which of course fails...)

Note that `requests` won't do any HTML entity escaping, but `BeautifulSoup` will try where it can, so, eg:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup1 = BeautifulSoup('smith & jones')
soup2 = BeautifulSoup('smith &amp; jones')
soup1, soup2
(<html><body><p>smith &amp; jones</p></body></html>,
 <html><body><p>smith &amp; jones</p></body></html>)
```

So, since you say "about half of the time" then it's because you've got 3 choices you're searching for that won't match.... try replacing the `&` in your `categories` with `&amp;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the improvements suggested on my script. But unfortunately, the code is still crashing. I tested printing the return of urlparse.urljoin() and I always have a well formed url. I can open it normally on a web browser. But when I send as argument to requests.get() it just crashes. Any more ideas of improvement would be welcome.

Comment: @XVirtusX how many times have you tried printing it? That's the only place your exception can come from... if not - you'll need to add the full traceback to your question... `requests.get` won't give the exception you specify

Comment: Well, after debugging for a while and reading more the docs of urlparse, I tried using urlparse.urlsplit() on the return of the urljoin and after that using geturl() and it finally worked. Don't know exactly why did it work. It seems I'm bumping in the obscure internals of python..